# mailx change sender name

Tags: email, sendmail, mailx

I understood that for changing sender's name with `mailx` I should do the following:

```
mailx -r newmail@mail.com -s "some subject" my@email.com
```

But when I do that, I get:

```
mailx: invalid option -- r
Usage: mail [-iInv] [-s subject] [-c cc-addr] [-b bcc-addr] to-addr ...
            [-- sendmail-options ...]
       mail [-iInNv] -f [name]
       mail [-iInNv] [-u user
```

Does anyone knows what's happening? 
thanks,

Comment: what are you trying to achieve with `-r`?

Comment: Change the sender's email. I think it works (`-r`) with newer version of mailx

Answer (score 2):

```
mailx -a 'From:name@your-domain.com' -s "Subject" my-best-friend@other-domain.com < text.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

The correct syntax is:

```
mailx -s "some subject" my@email.com -- -r newmail@mail.com
```

The Usage info shows "[-- sendmail-options ...]" and since "-r" is a sendmail option, you need to use the double dashes first.

Answer (score 1):

Tested with this and found to be working:

echo test | mailx -s "Mail Test" user@recipentdomain.com -- -f user@senderdomain.com

The double-dash before "-f" makes the mailx not to parse the -f, but only pass it to sendmail/postfix, which will then send with the "from" address mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to use `-a` to add sender name in header:

```
mailx -a "From:Sender Name <newmail@mail.com>" -s "some subject" my@email.com
```