# Send e-mail with custom From: and Cc:

Tags: linux, shell

I am trying to automate my email by using this command on unix VI:

```
echo 'Message body goes here' | mail -s 'subject line goes here' email@provider.com
```

However, I would like to add a "CC" and use a different email address showing when I send the email to the recipient.

Comment: I figured out the Cc but the from -r is not working on my system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mailx is usually link with mail.

Try passing the options to sendmail by putting double-dash at the end and then specifying -f (from) or -r (return):

```
mailx ....    -- -r returnname@domain.com

mailx ....    -- -f returnname@domain.com
```

You could also try "-a" option as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33128888/3196458)

```
mailx -a 'From:name@your-domain.com'  ...
```

If you want to try the sendmail:

```
sendmail -t <<EOF
To: toname@domain.com
Subject: Hi
From: fromname@domain.com
Reply-To: replyname@domain.com
Hello
EOF
```

Comment: mail : invalid option -- a

Comment: Did you try the  "  --   -r returnname@domain.com " with mailx (at the end of command line)?

Comment: Is it:     mailx -- -r 'emailaddress@provider'

Comment: Yes. For some reason, my browser was not able to add code, highlight, underscore characters. .... what you typed is correct. You put all the other options between mailx and the double-dashes.

Comment: I remember you mentioned that your mail doesn't support '-a', right? I guess then the REPLYTO as mentioned [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/380573/3196458) also wouldn't work for you?

Comment: Could you run `uname -a` and specify the output of it here?

Comment: If you are on Heirloom mailx, try the "-t" option as mentioned [here](http://serverfault.com/questions/172390/can-i-set-the-in-reply-to-header-when-using-the-linux-mail-command)

Comment: GNU / Linux 86/64

Comment: That doesn't seem to print the linux version. Try **cat /proc/version** OR **lsb_release -a** OR **uname -mrs** OR **cat /etc/*-release**. I have a feeling that you are on a older version of GNU/Linux. Your bet is probably to use sendmail directly.

Comment: Updated the answer to show how you could try sendmail.

Comment: Oh ok, I'll try that.

Comment: I've used -f with --.

Comment: Apparently, gmail is reporting that the mail may have not been sent by the sender.

Comment: Your problem may be related to SPF records. See [1](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22337593/3196458) & [2](http://stackoverflow.com/a/396/3196458).